# Oracle give two parameters on multiple rows to a subquery (or from a query to another)

Tags: oracle, join, parameters, subquery

I'm trying to give two parameters from a first query to a 2nd query :

```
SELECT t1.FAM,t2.CODE FROM (SELECT t1.FAM, t2.CODE FROM (SELECT num_family FROM family) t1, (SELECT num_code FROM code) t2)
```

So I have my two parameters (multiples lines):

```
FAM1 | CODE1
FAM1 | CODE2
FAM1 | CODE3
FAM2 | CODE1
FAM2 | CODE2
FAM2 | CODE3
```

So it's my two parameters and I want to put those two parameters to a 3rd request :

```
SELECT count(*) FROM stats WHERE num_fam LIKE '%FAM1%' AND num_code LIKE '%FAM1%';
```

To have :

```
FAM1 | CODE1 | 5
FAM1 | CODE2 | 2
FAM1 | CODE3 | 0
FAM2 | CODE1 | 9
FAM2 | CODE2 | 4
FAM2 | CODE3 | 1
```

But I don't understand how to combine those two queries and to give the two parameters from the first query to the second : I've try with subquery and inner join, but it was not a success... !

Comment: In both queries, is the last row supposed to be `FAM2`? In the first one the column names don't seem to be consistent. And in the second one are both likes really supposed to be using `FAM1`? And why are you using like at all? (Sample data might help...)

Comment: 1st question : Yes I supposed FAM2, I correct it. For the like it's because in the real request I'm doing a : SELECT (
        CASE
          WHEN LISTE LIKE '%#'|| t2.FAM ||'%'
          THEN (
            CASE
              WHEN LISTE LIKE '%#'|| t2.CODE||'%'
              THEN 1
              ELSE 0
            END)
          ELSE 0
        END). It's boring because I know exactly how to do it with PL/SQL : Two nested cursor with the SELECT count(*) FROM stats WHERE FAM= param1 AND CODE = param2. But I don't want to do it in PL/SQL because I want to have a result as a request.

Comment: So your `stats` table has `liste` values like, say, `'abc #FAM1 def #CODE1 ghi'`?

Answer (score 0):

Following is what I thought of...please check if this works:

```
SELECT COUNT (*)
  FROM stats
 WHERE     (num_fam, num_code) IN
              (SELECT t1.FAM, t2.CODE
                 FROM (SELECT num_family FROM family) t1,
                      (SELECT num_code FROM code) t2)
       AND NUM_FAM LIKE '%FAM1%' --I assumed this is a required filter .
       AND NUM_CODE LIKE '%FAM1%';
```

Comment: It's an interesting way of doing what I want, but in my "real" request, I have to do CASE
          WHEN LISTE LIKE '%#'|| t1.FAM ||'%'
          THEN (
            CASE
              WHEN LISTE LIKE '%#'|| t2.CODE ||'%'
              THEN 1
              ELSE 0
            END)
          ELSE 0
        END  instead of SELECT COUNT (*) FROM stats : So I can't join in the WHERE with a IN...

Comment: Ok...I guess then the issue is more of creating a close model of your "real" issue.  There was nothing like CASE and so on in the question and now it is there. So if you can revise your question to be as close to your real requirement  that will help all to review it further - in my opinion at least.

Answer (score 0):

You could use cross join and inner join

```
  SELECT t1.num_family, t2.CODE, count(*) 
  FROM family t1
  CROSS JOIN code t2 
  INNER JOIN stats t3 ON  t1.num_family LIKE '%FAM1%' AND t2.num_code LIKE '%FAM1%'
  GROUP BY t1.num_family, t2.CODE
```

Comment: I cannot put FAM1 or CODE1 in the request because it's dynamic and depending of the first request...

Comment: your comment have not sense to  me  .. you use in your query .. and why is not possible use the same value in the answer ?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're cross-joining the first two tables, e.g. with sample data to match what you showed as output:

```
-- CTE for implied sample data
with family (num_family) as (
            select 'FAM1' from dual
  union all select 'FAM2' from dual
),
code (num_code) as (
            select 'CODE1' from dual
  union all select 'CODE2' from dual
  union all select 'CODE3' from dual
)
-- actual query (edited from what you showed to be valid)
--SELECT t1.FAM,t2.CODE FROM (SELECT t1.FAM, t2.CODE FROM (SELECT num_family FROM family) t1, (SELECT num_code FROM code) t2)
SELECT t1.FAM, t2.CODE FROM (SELECT num_family as fam FROM family) t1, (SELECT num_code as code FROM code) t2
/

FAM  CODE 
---- -----
FAM1 CODE1
FAM1 CODE2
FAM1 CODE3
FAM2 CODE1
FAM2 CODE2
FAM2 CODE3
```

which doesn't even need those subqueries, as it's the same as:

```
select f.num_family, c.num_code from family f cross join code c
```

and you then want to get the count of matching `liste` values in your `stats` table, where both the family and code values are embedded in that string, preceded by a hash:

> I have to do CASE WHEN LISTE LIKE '%#'|| t1.FAM ||'%' THEN ( CASE WHEN LISTE LIKE '%#'|| t2.CODE ||'%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) ELSE 0 END instead of SELECT COUNT (*) FROM stats

You can do what with an outer join and boolean logic in the join condition, rather than trying to use a case expression:

```
-- CTE for implied sample data
with family (num_family) as (
            select 'FAM1' from dual
  union all select 'FAM2' from dual
),
code (num_code) as (
            select 'CODE1' from dual
  union all select 'CODE2' from dual
  union all select 'CODE3' from dual
),
stats (liste) as (
            select 'abc #FAM1 def #CODE1 ghi' from dual connect by level <= 5
  union all select 'jkl #CODE2#FAM1 mno' from dual connect by level <= 2
  union all select '#FAM2#CODE1' from dual connect by level <= 9
  union all select '#FAM2#CODE2' from dual connect by level <= 4
  union all select '#FAM2#CODE3' from dual
  union all select '#FAM2#CODE4' from dual -- no match
  union all select '#FAM3#CODE1' from dual -- no match
)
-- actual query
select f.num_family, c.num_code, count(s.liste) as matches
from family f
cross join code c
left join stats s on s.liste like '%#'|| f.num_family ||'%'
and s.liste like '%#'|| c.num_code ||'%'
group by f.num_family, c.num_code
order by f.num_family, c.num_code;

NUM_ NUM_C    MATCHES
---- ----- ----------
FAM1 CODE1          5
FAM1 CODE2          2
FAM1 CODE3          0
FAM2 CODE1          9
FAM2 CODE2          4
FAM2 CODE3          1
```

The `like` pattern is going to be problematic if the family or code values have overlapping roots, or unexpected partial matches. E.g. if you had a `liste` values of `#FAM10#CODE20` it would still match against `FAM1` and `CODE2`. You could maybe switch to `regexp_like()` if you can define a pattern to avoid those false matches (e.g. followed by space/punctuation/EOL).